# Is this the correct way to check with javascript if a radio button is checked?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the below code but it is not working. Is this correct?

```
var diffLvl = document.getELementById('lvlDiff');
var interLvl = document.getElementById('lvlInter');
var simpLvl = document.getElementById('lvlSimple');

if (simpLvl.checked) {
    //do stuff
  } else if (interLvl.checked){
    //do stuff
  } else {
    //do stuff
  }
```

Comment: You need to get to know your debugging tools, first thing I do when my code doesn't do what I intended it to do is to check Firefox's error console, it will almost always have a decent error message.

Comment: @eBusiness I used Chrome's console and it gave an error but it definitely did not lead me to this. I probably should use firefox's this is the second time I have been suggested firefox's console.

Comment: The trick is to learn how to read error messages. Although error messages are very comprehensive nowadays (compared to for example "ERROR 141"), they still only report what's gone wrong, not exactly what the reason is for that. :)

Comment: Get Firebug while you are at it, pretty good tool for the more intricate code analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `[...]getEL[...]` on the first line. The `L` should be lowercase.

Comment: ah... thanks, I didn't notice that, thats probably the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I've spent HOURS on problems such as this. Especially when sleepy :)

Comment: Yeah, thankfully I only spent about 10 mins. Thats whats good about SO :)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's correct except for a spelling error.

Javascript is case sensetive. Change `getELementById` to `getElementById`.